# Need clarification for Swift Type Properties

Tags: swift

Apple's swift documentation on Type Properties states:

"For value types (that is, structures and enumerations), you can define stored and computed type properties. For classes, you can define computed type properties only."

The wording in this paragraph is confusing. So, I can define ***stored and computed type properties*** in structures and enumerations, but I can only define ***computed type properties*** in classes? That would be odd because apple gives an example where they define *stored and computed properties* in a class:

```
struct SomeStructure {
  static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
  static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
  // return an Int value here
  }
}

enum SomeEnumeration {
 static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
 static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
 // return an Int value here
 }
}

class SomeClass {
  static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
  static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
   // return an Int value here
  }
  class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
  // return an Int value here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the stored property in the class is a `static` property. But you'll notice there's no stored property in the class that is a `class` property; that's what's unsupported:

```
class SomeClass {
  static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
  static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
   // return an Int value here
  }
  // class var overrideableStoredTypeProperty = "Some value." // NO
  class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
  // return an Int value here
  }
}
```

Comment: More clearly, `class var storedClassProperty = "Some Value"` would not compile.  It produces `Class stored properties not yet supported in classes; did you mean 'static'?`

Comment: @nhgrif NO means NO :)

Comment: Oh... you know what... I didn't read your answer... I compiled it.  As such, I ignored the commented out lines...

Comment: @nhgrif Well, I didn't want to write an example that wouldn't compile... :)))

Comment: I would have never understood this from just the documentation alone. One last thing: Why is there a *class* keyword and a *static* keyword to declare class type properties?

Comment: Static is static. It isn't overrideable by subclasses. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_properties_and_methods